# Binding off Visibility of another element - and inverting

Tags: wpf, silverlight, binding

I'd like to make Control A visibile if Control B is hidden, and vice versa.  Right now I have this converter:

```
public class InvertVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter {

    public Object Convert(Object value, Type targetType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        if (targetType == typeof(Visibility)) {
            Visibility vis = (Visibility)value;
            return vis == Visibility.Collapsed ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Converter can only convert to value of type Visibility.");
    }

    public Object ConvertBack(Object value, Type targetType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        throw new Exception("Invalid call - one way only");
    }
}
```

And this XAML:

```
<Button Visibility="{Binding ElementName=btn1, Path=Visibility, Converter={StaticResource InvertVisibilityConverter}}">Btn2</Button>
```

Which works.  I'm just wondering if there's a more direct way in WPF / Silverlight to accomplish this?  I don't mind having a converter, I just want to make sure there's no better way I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Bottom line, I see no problem with what you are doing.

That said, if you have a property in the ViewModel to which Control A binds to control its visibility, I would bind Control B to the same property and invert the visibily via a separate converter.  I'm not sure if I can articulate why, but that seems more natural to me (at least in lieu of any additional context around what you are doing).

Comment: There's more context :)  Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 33):

In this case you could do it with triggers. Example with two Buttons

```
<Button Name="button1">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=button2, Path=Visibility}" Value="Visible">
                    <Setter Property="Button.Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
<Button Name="button2"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  The style trigger seems to me a bit more cumbersome than the converter, but that's a matter of personal preference.

Comment: I agree with you. Just thought I'd post another way of doing it :)

Comment: I really like this approach, it reduces the amount of code behind.

Answer (score 3):

What you doing is fine but I tend to prefer more general converters and to keep symmetry with the built in converters.

So I would do a InverseBooleanToVisibiltyConverter that accepts booleans and returns visibility types. This matches with the built in BoolenToVisibiltyConverter

Then I would bind to the IsVisible property of the button not the Visibility property.

But that is a matter of preference really.